# iCalendar string to Calendar

Tags: android, icalendar

I have an iCalendar format string, like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar
I want to trasform it in a Calendar object.
How can I do this? I must parse the string myself or there are some methods that do this?

EDIT:
At the last I make this solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
String[] split=s.split("\n|(:)");
                for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
                    if(split[i].contains("DTSTART")){
                        //next String contain the data start
                        String s1=split[i+1];
                        s1=s1.replace("T", "");//remove T
                        s1=s1.replace("00Z", "");//remove final part
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                        Date date;
                        try {
                            date = sdf.parse(s1);
                            Log.d("", "START "+date.getTime());
                            intent.putExtra("beginTime",date.getTime());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    if(split[i].contains("DTEND")){
                        //next string contains the data end
                        String s1=split[i+1];
                        s1=s1.replace("T", "");//remove T
                        s1=s1.replace("00Z", "");//remove final part
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                        Date date;
                        try {
                            date = sdf.parse(s1);
                            Log.d("", "END "+date.getTime());
                            intent.putExtra("endTime", date.getTime());
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    if(split[i].contains("LOCATION")){
                        //next string contains location
                        Log.d("", "Luogo "+split[i+1]);
                        intent.putExtra("eventLocation",split[i+1]);

                    }

                    if(split[i].contains("DESCRIPTION")){
                        //next string contains location
                        Log.d("", "Descrizione "+split[i+1]);
                        intent.putExtra("description",split[i+1]);

                    }

                    if(split[i].contains("SUMMARY")){
                        //next string contains title
                        Log.d("", "Titolo "+split[i+1]);
                        intent.putExtra("title",split[i+1]);

                    }

                }
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about your specific problem.  Android's `Calendar` is not a calendar in the usual sense but a way of obtaining information about a specific date/time.  If you want direct translation of an ICalendar file you need to either use an existing library such as [ical4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/) or write your own parsing system to obtain the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out iCal4j library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/) . It may help you.

Comment: I don't want create .ics file, just Calendar object in Android.